# sentry install error in step webpack -p --bail

Tags: webpack, sentry

install sentry 8.0.0 with:

```
pip install -e .
```

got following error:

```
running [webpack]
Container#eachAtRule is deprecated. Use Container#walkAtRules instead.
Container#eachRule is deprecated. Use Container#walkRules instead.
Container#eachDecl is deprecated. Use Container#walkDecls instead.
Node#removeSelf is deprecated. Use Node#remove.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/sentry/sentry/setup.py", line 264, in run
    self._build_static()
  File "/www/sentry/sentry/setup.py", line 306, in _build_static
    cwd=work_path, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['node_modules/.bin/webpack', '-p', '--bail']' returned non
-zero exit status -9
unable to build Sentry's static assets!
Hint: You might be running an invalid version of NPM.

----------------------------------------
Command "/www/sentry/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize; __file__='/www/sentry/sentry/setup.py'; exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps" failed with error code 1 in /www/sentry/sentry
```

I had tried npm@5.0.0 npm@4.1 npm@2.11.2 all did't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might try is this to see if you get a better error:

- Pull down the Sentry source code
- Run "npm install" from the Sentry root directory

We require Node 0.10.x or newer, but it should run on the latest versions as well. I believe we test on 0.10 and 0.12 locally.

Comment: thanks! I retry use version of node 0.10.40 is work, but node-v0.12.6 has the same error.